# how to embed XHTML in XML without DOCTYPE, CDATA or escapes?

Tags: xml, xhtml, schema, doctype, dtd

Is there any way embed XHTML entity references into XML text without the DOCTYPE DTD declaration?  The DOCTYPE line is causing problems on the java server it's targeting.

Escaping the &; sequence isn't acceptable, nor is embedding in CDATA.  The references need to be validated.

Is is possible to reference the DTD from the schema definition instead of the XML data file.

More broadly speaking, what is the common practice for embedding XHTML (or at least entity references) in XML and having that validated?

One potential solution is to convert the entire XHTML 1.0 DTD to a schema, but this doesn't sound like the best idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a DOCTYPE without PUBLIC or SYSTEM identifiers?

You can either add the ENTITY declarations directly to the internal subset:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
<!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
<!ENTITY laquo  "&#171;">
<!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
<!ENTITY deg    "&#176;">
<!ENTITY plusmn "&#177;">
<!ENTITY sup2   "&#178;">
<!ENTITY sup3   "&#179;">
<!ENTITY frac14 "&#188;">
<!ENTITY frac12 "&#189;">
<!ENTITY frac34 "&#190;">
]>
<foo/>
```

or you can use a parameter entity to point to an external file/files that have your ENTITY declarations:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ENTITY % ents SYSTEM "xhtml-lat1.ent">
%ents;
]>
<foo/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The XML is not well formed if you have entity references other than the 5 pre-defined ones, and don't have a doctype.

You simplify things greatly if you use numeric character references rather than named entity references so use

`&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;`

Either by modifying the original generation if you control that, or just expanding the entities by using any xml parser or a simple text replace using perl or equivalent. You can get full list of the html(5) entity set in dtd or json or other formats here http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/

Answer (score 0):

One may be able to use the SAX [`EntityResolver2.getExternalSubset()`](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ext/EntityResolver2.html#getExternalSubset(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Allows applications to provide an external subset for documents that don't explicitly define one. Documents with DOCTYPE declarations that omit an external subset can thus augment the declarations available for validation, entity processing, and attribute processing (normalization, defaulting, and reporting types including ID).
>
> This method can also be used with documents that have no DOCTYPE declaration. When the root element is encountered, but no DOCTYPE declaration has been seen, this method is invoked.

Unfortunately the latter (having `getExternalSubset()` invoked when no DOCTYPE is present) is not happening with the JDK JAXP implementation vs. plugging genuine Xerces into the runtime, for example.  Nevertheless, I've used this successfully in practice – see [flyingsaucer@`19b962fb0a72`](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/commit/19b962fb0a72).

---

**UPDATE:**

> Unfortunately the latter (having `getExternalSubset()` invoked when no DOCTYPE is present) is not happening with the JDK JAXP implementation...

I've found:

- [JDK-6524460](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6524460): EntityResolver2 no longer used in Java6 (Created: 2007-02-13)

and then I've reported:

- [JDK-8305253](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8305253): Broken org.xml.sax.ext.EntityResolver2.getExternalSubset() behavior

outlining one more case of `getExternalSubset()` not working as expected with the JDK-supplied implementation.  Again, all of it appears to work as expected using the original Xerces2 implementation.